# javascript - is it possible to get country name we selected in SYSTEM's timezone . we can get offset (like 5.5)but how to get country name

Tags: javascript

in JAVASCRIPT, is it possible to get country name that we selected in our system . for example if my system timezone is "india/kolkata" , we can get offset value like this :

```
d = new Date()
utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset()*60000)

offset = (d.getTime()-utc)/3600000
```

thus offset is the required value like 5.5 for india .
But i donno getting the country name . 
I thought of getting the country name by mapping the offset with the country name from my database of timezones . but i found that some countries have same timezones . for example, india and srilanka are two countries that have same timezones with offset 5.5 . So, how to get the correct country name in javascript from system's  timezone .

thanks

Comment: Is this server-side (Node.JS) or client-side JavaScript? Anyway, using the timezone to determine someone's country seems like a strange idea.

Comment: client side javascript , and NO internet access allowed , but u can use some localdatabase like some timezones list in csv format . 
if my idea is strange , then plz leave the idea, give me good idea, what i want is, when i open my app, it should show , you are from the country "country" . if that is not possible, plz tell that its not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For client-side JavaScript, simple answer: you can't. As you said, there can be (and generally is) multiple countries in the same timezone, with the exact same offset.

I don't see any other reliable way to get the user country in pure JavaScript.

Why not simply ask your visitor?

Comment: ok thanks for the answer ! and thanks for taking time to respond me

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Geolocation API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/geolocation/trip_meter/) where it is supported would help you make the 'default' assumption, however letting the user to manually pick his location from country list is still highly recommended (some people use proxies).

Comment: This won't actually work without any internet connection, as it was indicated in the comments. The Geolocation API uses remote IP / WiFi databases to determine actual user position.